# Python For loop only taking odd index from list

Tags: python

```
free_spacelunn = 900
disksize = [100,60,89,50,40,10,90,89,76]

print(disksize)

if (len(disksize) > 0):

    for valy in disksize:



        print(valy)
        if(valy < free_spacelunn):

            free_spacelunn = free_spacelunn - valy
            disksize.remove(valy)
            print(free_spacelunn)
print(disksize)
--------------
'''
For loop is only taking odd index value not sure why, there are two print statment for debug. Sample out put is tagged below.
[100, 60, 89, 50, 40, 10, 90, 89, 76]
100
800
89
711
40
671
90
581
76
505
[60, 50, 10, 89]
```

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, this should be asked on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You remove elements from list `disksize` that iterated in `for`. Don't do this.

Comment: free_spacelunn = 900
disksize = [100,60,89,50,40,10,90,89,76,67]


print(disksize)

if (len(disksize) > 0):
    disksize1 = disksize
    print(disksize1)
    for valy in disksize1:
        
        
        
        print(valy)
        if(valy < free_spacelunn):
                
            free_spacelunn = free_spacelunn - valy
            disksize.remove(valy)
            print(free_spacelunn)
                
        
        
print(disksize1)

Comment: same issue even after copying list to another list and substituting value from orginal list.